# I think it is a bug. ModelSim cannot be called from Quartus on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, modelsim, quartus

1. I have Quartus Prime Lite 21.1 installed on Ubuntu 20.04 and it is working fine.
2. I also have ModelSim 20.1.1 and it is working fine
3. I've put the right path to ModelSim on Quartus Prime, and it can even recognize the version (unfortunantly, I'm not allowed to put the pictures here, but, belive me, this part I did it right). I've tried 2 variations:

   a) /home/domvito55/intelFPGA_lite/20.1/modelsim_ase/bin

   and

   b) /home/domvito55/intelFPGA_lite/20.1/modelsim_ase/linuxaloem
4. But when I try to run ModelSim from inside Quartus, it does not open! And I get the following message which is pretty odd, as I've never installed Questa, and I didn't even put a directory path for Questa.

> Error: You selected ModelSim as Simulation Software in EDA Tool
> Settings, however NativeLink found Questa Intel FPGA in the path --
> correct path or change EDA Tool Settings and try again Error:
> NativeLink simulation flow was NOT successful

I've spent all day today trying a bunch of stuff, but I couldn't solve it.

I'll put the transcription of the log file in the end.

**Log file**

Info: Start Nativelink Simulation process

========= EDA Simulation Settings =====================

Sim Mode : Gate
Family : maxii
Quartus root : /home/domvito55/intelFPGA_lite/21.1/quartus/linux64/
Quartus sim root : /home/domvito55/intelFPGA_lite/21.1/quartus/eda/sim_lib
Simulation Tool : modelsim
Simulation Language : vhdl
Version : 93
Simulation Mode : GUI
Sim Output File : somador1bit.vho
Sim SDF file : somador1bit__vhdl.sdo
Sim dir : simulation/modelsim

=======================================================

Info: Starting NativeLink simulation with ModelSim software
Sourced NativeLink script /home/domvito55/intelFPGA_lite/21.1/quartus/common/tcl/internal/nativelink/modelsim.tcl
Error: You selected ModelSim as Simulation Software in EDA Tool Settings, however NativeLink found Questa Intel FPGA in the path -- correct path or change EDA Tool Settings and try again
Error: NativeLink simulation flow was NOT successful

================The following additional information is provided to help identify the cause of error while running nativelink scripts=================
Nativelink TCL script failed with errorCode: issued_nl_message
Nativelink TCL script failed with errorInfo: You selected ModelSim as Simulation Software in EDA Tool Settings, however NativeLink found Questa Intel FPGA in the path -- correct path or change EDA Tool Settings and try again
while executing
"error "$emsg" "" "issued_nl_message""
invoked from within
"if [ catch {exec $vsim_cmd -version} version_str] {
set emsg "Can't launch $tool Simulation software -- make sure the software is properly installed..."
(procedure "launch_sim" line 88)
invoked from within
"launch_sim launch_args_hash"
("eval" body line 1)
invoked from within
"eval launch_sim launch_args_hash"
invoked from within
"if [ info exists ::errorCode ] {
set savedCode $::errorCode
set savedInfo $::errorInfo
error $result $..."
invoked from within
"if [catch {eval launch_sim launch_args_hash} result ] {
set status 1
if [ info exists ::errorCode ] {
set save..."
(procedure "run_sim" line 74)
invoked from within
"run_sim run_sim_args_hash"
invoked from within
"if [ info exists ::errorCode ] {
set savedCode $::errorCode
set savedInfo $::errorInfo
error "$result" $savedInfo ..."
(procedure "run_eda_simulation_tool" line 334)
invoked from within
"run_eda_simulation_tool eda_opts_hash"

Answer (score 0):

I met the same questions in archlinux and solved the problem by replacing quartus 2021 to quartus13.0 (quartus130 in aur).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found the solution.
The model sim software that came bundled with quartus is no more available from version 21 and onwards.

In my case my issue was resolved after i installed quartus 20 and model sim 20 from the intel website for linux.
you dont need to uninstall 21 , just install quartus lite 20 and the bundled model sim 20 and you are good to go